# What exactly is a hash in regards to JSON?

Tags: json, hash, hashmap

I am learning JSON, but I found out that you can put what are called "hashes" into JSON as well? Where can I find out what a hash is? Or could you explain to me what a hash is? Also, what's a hashmap? I have experience in C++ and C#, and I am learning JS, Jquery, and JSON.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A Hash is a sparse array that uses arbitrary strings/objects (depending on the implementation, this varies across programming languages) rather than plain integers as keys.

In Javascript, any Object is technically a hash (also referred to as a Dictionary, Associative-Array, etc).

Examples:

```js
var myObj = {}; // Same as = new Object();
myObj['foo'] = 'bar';

var myArr = []; // Same as = new Array();
myArr[0] = 'foo';
myArr[1] = 'bar';
myArr['blah'] = 'baz'; // This will work, but is not recommended.
```

Now, since JSON is basically using JS constructs and some strict guidelines to define portable data, the equivalent to myObj above would be:

```js
{ "foo" : "bar" };
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: A note about your last line: you can set properties on arrays as if they were objects--they *are* objects, and will act like objects in that case.

Comment: In Javascript, an Object is not "technically a hash", because "hash" is not the technical term for a hash map or dictionary or associative array etc.

Answer (score 16):

Hash = dictionary.

A hash:

```
{ "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2" }
```

Answer (score 5):

JSON supports dictionary type elements. People may refer to these as hash tables, which are a type of data structure.
Referring to JSON dictionaries as hash tables would be technically incorrect, however, as there is no particular data structure implementation associated with the JSON data itself.

A hash is a random looking number which is generated from a piece of data and always the same for the same input. For example if you download files from some websites they will provide a hash of the data so you can verify your download is not corrupted (which would change the hash).
Another application of hashes is in a hash table (or hash map). This is a very fast associative data structure where the hashes are used to index into an array. std::unorderd_map in C++ is an example of this.
You could store a hash in JSON as a string for example something like "AB34F553" and use this to verify data.

Answer (score 0):

On [json.org](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), a JSON "object" is "a collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed list, or associative array."

Using the ambiguous term "hash" for a JSON object is confusing. "Hash" is indeed used in the wild as short-hand for: hash map, dictionary, key-value structure, etc.  But it is also short-hand for: the hash value that is computed by a hash function.