# Why finding object keys has lower complexity than array lookup in javascript?

Tags: javascript, v8

I need to map accented letters (é, ü, á, ï, ö, ..., etc.) to their corresponding letters in English (e, u, a, i, o, ..., etc.).

I know I can do this in several approaches:

1. Looping through an array - complexity O(n):

```
const mappingArray = [
   ['é', 'e'],
   ['ü', 'u'],
   ['á', 'a'],
   ['ï', 'i'],
   ['ö', 'o']
];

accentedToEnglish(accented) {
    for (let i = 0; i < mappingArray.length; i++ ) {
      if (mappingArray[i][0] === accented)
            return mappingArray[i][1];
     }
}
```

2. Accessing object keys - complexity O(1):

```
const mappingObject = {
   'é': 'e',
   'ü': 'u',
   'á': 'a',
   'ï': 'i',
   'ö': 'o'
};

accentedToEnglish(accented) {
    return mappingObject[accented];
}
```

Why is the complexity of the mapping above using object keys = O(1) in javascript? Does't the javascript engine iterate through all the keys behind the scenes in order to find the exact value?

Comment: No, objects are implemented as hash tables so that lookup is amortized O(1).

Comment: in a way its like accessing array elements if you know the index. so an array is also like an object `{0:['é', 'e'], 1:['ü', 'u']...}` . `mappingArray['0'][1]` is like `mappingObject['é']`

Comment: Strictly speaking, objects are not usually implemented as hash maps, but JS engines do use hash maps and/or binary search to speed up various operations (such as: caching the result of performing a property lookup on an object that's in "struct mode", not in "hash map mode"). **Pro tip: for patterns like this example, `Map`s will be even faster than regular objects with properties.**

Comment: "Doesn't the javascript engine iterate through all the keys behind the scenes in order to find the exact value?" ... it might, but I guess that's still faster than whatever loop one can write in JavaScript ...

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, objects are implemented as hashes. Which means the keys are fed to a hash function which computes an address in O(1) average and amortized time. To understand more about the complexity of hash tables you could look at:
[Hash table runtime complexity (insert, search and delete)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214353/hash-table-runtime-complexity-insert-search-and-delete)

For a quick explanation also take a look at the answer of:
[What exactly is a hash in regards to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364289/what-exactly-is-a-hash-in-regards-to-json)
and [Complexity of accessing data in an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266944/complexity-of-accessing-data-in-an-object).

Comment: This is incorrect in general (the specification does not guarantee the lookup time for object keys, it does for `Map` keys) but it might very well be true for certain object representations of certain engines.